# Best Practices in organising data related code/files (Firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase, architecture, code-organization

Hello I am newbie and working on firebase based android apps and learning to code from myself.

I have some queries,Firstly I have not learned Android Architectures Pattern and having some difficulties in learning them.
This is my question

**What if I structured my project in this manner**

---

This file reads/writes/listens data from server

```
DataManager.java

public class DataManager(){
  Context context;
  public void DataManager(Context context){
    this.context = context;
   }

  public void readData(){
     ...firebase code....
      trigger EventBus/LocalBroadcast

  }  

  public void writeData(Data data){
     ...firebase code....
      trigger EventBus/LocalBroadcast

  }  
   }
```

This file will do all the server stuff and will trigger events on callbacks

and In BaseApplication.java
    I will instantiate this file
and Activity/Fragments will response  on Data recieved

Is it better approach?

(Please dont downvote this question simply comment "this is a bad question" I will remove this thread because I have to earn 80+ reputations for entering into android developer's group of chat.stackoverflow)